# Spring Cloud - SQS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I'm trying to get a simple queue handler working with the Spring Cloud framework. I've successfully got the message handler polling the queue, However. The problem I'm seeing is that when I post a message to the queue, my handler is failing to unmarshall the payload in to the required java Object.

```
@MessageMapping("MyMessageQueue")
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public void handleCreateListingMessage(@Headers Map<String, String> headers, MyMessage message) {
    //do something with the MyMessage object
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
No converter found to convert to class MyMessage
```

As I understand it, the @MessageMapping should use Jackson to unmarshall my JSON payload into a MyMessage object. However its complaining that it cannot find a converter.

Has anyone come across this?

I'm using the 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version of Spring Cloud.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jackson is only used if a `contentType` header is set with value `application/json` on the SQS message. Otherwise the converters do not know what type of content is contained in the message's payload and the right converter cannot be chosen.

If you use `QueueMessagingTemplate#convertAndSend` as in the [reference application](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/aws-refapp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/sample/sqs/SqsController.java#L60), the `contentType` header will automatically be set.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up. I can confirm MyMessage object are now being created as expected after adding the contentType header.

Comment: If you happen to send SQS message by means other than Spring Cloud (like aws console or aws cli) and you have no idea how to "set header", then do not despair. Simply add a message attribute with name `contentType`, type `String` and value `application/json` which makes Spring Cloud on receiving end pickup Jackson.