# Spring cloud aws (messaging) - not getting message

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, annotations, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I am attempting to get spring cloud to work with messaging using auto configure.

My properties file contains:

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=xxxxxxxxxx
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=xxxxxxxxxx

cloud.aws.region.static=us-west-2
```

My Configuration class is as follows:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

My Listener class:

```
@RestController
public class OrderListener {

@MessageMapping("orderQueue")
public void orderListener(Order order){

    System.out.println("Order Name " + order.getName());
    System.out.println("Order Url" + order.getUrl());

    }

}
```

However, nothing seems to print out. I've verified that my queue is in the right region and there is a message on the queue thats ready to be received.

Can someone please provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three possible reasons why it is not working

1. The *OrderListener* class is not scanned by the component scanner. In order to be scanned this class must be in the same package as your *Application* class or in a sub-package.
2. The spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure artifact is missing on you classpath and therefore the AmazonSQS client is not automatically configured and the queues are not registered.
3. The message you have in your queue is missing a message header *contentType* with value *application/json* (for more information about this see question [Spring Cloud - SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723439/spring-cloud-sqs)).